# react-native-keep-awake "null is not an object"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to keep my react-native screen awake when the camera is on, so i downloaded react-native-keep-awake to try that package for my purposes. I followed the documentation and couldn't get the package working.

Here are my steps...

- Downloaded npm pacakage (npm install react-native-keep-awake --save)
- Installed pod file (cd ios && pod install)
- Imported the package (import KeepAwake from 'react-native-keep-awake')
- Used in my screen...

```
useEffect(()=> {
  if(isRecording) {
    KeepAwake.activate();
  } else {
    KeepAwake.deactivate();     
  }
}, [isRecording]);
```

I've also tried to work with the non-deprecated packages... "@sayem314/react-native-keep-awake": "^1.1.0", && "react-native-idle-timer": "^2.1.7",

Same error....

```
null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.KeepAwake.active')
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keep-awake

Comment: Have you called `react-native link react-native-keep-awake`?

Comment: @DavidScholz - i have, but i keep getting the error - error Unrecognized command "link".